# Using GMail Account to Sync Corporate Exchange Account

Tags: email, exchange, gmail

On an iPhone I can set it up to use my corporate exchange email account.  When new mail arrives I get it on my iPhone and also in Outlook.

Is there a way that I can get this type of syncing working via a GMail Account? ie. create an account called johnsmith@gmail.com and then reference my corporate exchange account?

I have managed to get it setup so that I can send an email from my corporate account via the GMail interface but I havent been able to fill my inbox with my exchange emails.

Comment: If you use Outlook Web Access (OWA) you do have a browser GUI, too (although not as great as GMail but purely usable from a browser, too).

Comment: I'm trying to set it up via GMail so I can then use Chrome and the offline option. That way I can get rid of Outlook

Comment: Does your mail provider support POP?  https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=21288

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this really is to ask your server administrators to forward all emails sent to your address to your gmail account as well, however this won't mark things as read etc.